# Android MipMap - How to create image resources in XML

Tags: android, xml, drawable, mipmaps

I've noticed for a while now that Android Studio has "mipmap" folders in the project directory. From what I understand, in order to make sure we have consistency of image resources across all devices (in-app icons) we should have image resources in XML format such as the one shown below:

```
    <!-- drawable/numeric-1-box.xml -->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#757575"
        android:pathData="M14,17H12V9H10V7H14M19,3H5A2,2 0 0,0 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5A2,2 0 0,0 19,3Z" />
</vector>
```

I've been using the [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) site to get most of my general icons in XML format. However, how do I go about creating icons like these? So far I've been downloading them from the site shown above. Is there a tool I can use to export my images to these format (XML)? What is the procedure to do so? Photoshop, Illustrator or some other image converting web tool? Any help on how to create these images would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've noticed for a while now that Android Studio has "mipmap" folders in the project directory.

Note that this has nothing to do with anything else in the rest of your question. Vector drawables would go in `res/drawable-nodpi/`, not a `mipmap` directory.

> From what I understand, in order to make sure we have consistency of image resources across all devices (in-app icons) we should have image resources in XML format such as the one shown below:

Only if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, or if you are using a library that provides a backport of `VectorDrawable`. Android 1.0 through 4.4 did not have support for `<vector>` drawables.

> how do I go about creating icons like these?

I would start by creating an SVG file representing your icon. You can work with SVG natively using tools like Inkscape, and other graphics tools (e.g., Adobe Illustrator) can export in SVG. The `<path>` that you see in that XML is based on the SVG path specification.

From there, you can either create the `<vector>` drawable [manually](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/vector-graphics-in-android-converting-svg-to-vectordrawable/) or use [tools](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) to perform the SVG->`VectorDrawable` conversion.